# ServiceStack virtual directories collide with SPA routing

Tags: servicestack

I was previously using SharpPagesFeature with a FallbackService to handle SPA fallback. I have a route called `/modules`. However, some part of ServiceStack registers a virtual directory at that same path (also some additional root level virtual dirs). This caused ServiceStack to handle the path with StaticFileHandler instead of it being handled by FallbackService.

So I removed the FallbackService and SharpPagesFeature, added a HandlerFactoryPath and wrote a .NET Core rewrite rule instead. The rewrite rule ignore anything under my HandlerFactoryPath.

Now my SPA routes work but the API Explorer is broken with these messages in the console:

[image]

Additionally, you can see there are still files being fetched from root level instead of /api. Leading to future possible collisions.

[image]

Reasonably all ServiceStack activity should move in under HandlerFactoryPath when specified.

How do I solve this and still be able to keep using API Explorer (and possibly other Servicestack features)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[/modules](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/main/ServiceStack/src/ServiceStack/modules) is the embedded resource directory where all ServiceStack built-in UIs are stored, as such taking over the `/modules` route will prevent all built-in UIs from working.

Comment: Considering people use ServiceStack for all kinds of purposes a resource directory with 
 some kind of ServiceStack specific prefix would be better?

Comment: Or accessing it under /{HandlerFactoryPath}/modules?

Comment: Embedded resources paths are compiled into the .dll, they can't be changed at runtime. It's the single folder containing all built-in UIs so any other folder wont have conflicts. It's too late to rename modules now that it's been released. We don't plan on it, but if we ever add new embedded resource folders in SS we'll look at using a more unique name.